# saving api call data with multiple calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, async-await, promise

I am unable to get the data in a variable so that I can use it in my code. Right now, the Map returned from the second async function, `joinData`, logs onto the console, but I am not able to access it in my code, which I test by `console.log`-ing the variable afterwards. I have tried:

- Saving it as "d" in `joinData().then(d => data = d)`
- I also tried replicating it as a Map in the same block, but I always get "undefined" when I `console.log`
- Saving data as `joinedData` in the call
- Almost every combination I could think of, but each results in `undefined` or `Pending <Promise>`.

```
    const getWkItems = async function fetchAllReviewStats(
        endpoint = "review_statistics"
    ) {
        let requests = {
            method: "GET",
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + apiToken },
        };
        let results = new Array();
    
        let nextUrl = `https://api.wanikani.com/v2/${endpoint}`;
        while (nextUrl) {
            let resp = await fetch(nextUrl, requests);
            if (resp.ok) {
                let body = await resp.json();
                nextUrl = body.pages.next_url;
                results.push(...body.data);
            } else {
                throw Error(`${resp.status}: ${resp.statusText}`);
            }
        }
        return results;
    };
    
    //get review data
    const joinData = async () => {
        const reviewStats = new Map();
        const getReviewStats = await getWkItems("review_statistics").then((data) => {
            data.forEach((d) => {
                reviewStats.set(d.data.subject_id, {
                    updated_at: d.data_updated_at,
                    ...d.data,
                });
            });
        });
    
        //get map of subjects
        const subjects = new Map();
        const getSubjects = await getWkItems("subjects").then((data) => {
            data.forEach((d) => {
                subjects.set(d.id, {
                    updated_at: d.data_updated_at,
                    slug: d.data.slug,
                    meanings: d.data.meanings,
                    characters: d.data.characters,
                    readings: d.data.readings,
                    level: d.data.level,
                });
            });
        });
        //sort data
        let sortedReviewStats = new Map(
            Array.from(reviewStats.entries()).sort(
                (e1, e2) => Date.parse(e2[1].updated_at) - Date.parse(e1[1].updated_at)
            )
        );
    
        //connect subject to sorted data view
        const joinedData = new Map();
        sortedReviewStats.forEach((d, id) => {
            joinedData.set(id, { ...d, subject: subjects.get(id) }); //this looks up subject by its id
        });
    
        return joinedData;
    };
    joinData().then(d => console.log(d))
```

Comment: I've requested an API_TOKEN to help you, but I have no review stats to "play with"... all I get is what I've put in a [new repository](https://github.com/balexandre/so67752658) ... maybe you can tell me how to fill review stats data into wanikani (or create an temporary API token and delete after you're happy) to help a bit more?

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the code with your new token, but I see no issues (updated the output in the readme), I'm using `axios` (you mentioned NodeJs is a tag, and axios is so much better than fetch for the backend), but maybe you can clone the repo and run it to check by yourself?

Comment: I am actually only using frontend. I was able to solve it by calling the data in another async function, as suggested by the answer. I never use vanilla js, and generally use Svelte or React which was always more straightforward...thanks for your help! If I need backend I'll definitely use axios - seems much easier.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because, you are trying to access the results before all the Promises are resolved, try something like this:

```
try {
  let results = await joinData();
  console.log(results);
}catch(e){
// error handling here
}
```

Just make sure, the current function is `async` as well, within which this code will be. After this, whenever you log `results` it will not be `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes the issue was that I was trying to access it outside an async function.

Comment: Great, I am happy my answer was useful.